# Convex hull with n points using computational geometry libraries

Tags: postgis, gdal, spatial-database, geos, convex-hull

I've been searching for a function to make the Convex Hull of a Spatial Object with N points, to make an spatial approximation with n-corners, as shown in the article "Comparison of Approximations of Complex Objects Used for Approximation-based Query Processing in Spatial Database Systems", by Thomas Brinkhoff, Hans-Peter Kriegel and Ralf Schneider.
I haven't found any function to make this, I searched for any GEOS function but didn't find. Does anybody know what can I use for it?

Comment: After reading the [article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.443.8396&rep=rep1&type=pdf), I don't believe there is a function that provides the functionality that you want.  Am I correct in thinking you are refering to the minimum bounding N corner refered to in section 2.4?

Comment: GEOS has an implementation of [Convex Hull](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1ConvexHull.html), which uses the [Graham Scan algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan).. CH rather than n-C according in the section @MickyT refers to

Comment: [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/index.html) may be worth looking into as well.  I didn't find anything specific in there, but I only gave it a cursory glance.

Comment: @MickyT Yes, the question is refering to the minimum bounding N corner. It is a convex hull with a fixed set of points (like 5, or 7). We have looked into CGAL library but without success.

Comment: @AndersonCarniel You might find something on the math stack, the trick is knowing what to search for.  This looked hopeful, but I don't have time to investigate further into it at the moment. [math SE](http://mathoverflow.net/q/11580) question that sort of led me to [this](http://web.informatik.uni-bonn.de/I/GeomLab////MatrixMaximum/index.html).  Still not quite what you want I think, but could get you there.

Comment: @AndersonCarniel In the CGAL library [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs368-00-spring/TA/manuals/CGAL/ref-manual2/Optimisation/computing_maximum_area_inscribed_k_gon.html) was the sort of thing I though may do what you want

Answer (score 3):

[ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html)

> It is often used to determine an affected area based on a set of point observations.

Also worth nothing,

> It is usually used with MULTI and Geometry Collections. Although it is not an aggregate - you can use it in conjunction with ST_Collect to get the convex hull of a set of points. ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(somepointfield)).

So run inputs to `ST_Collect` first if you're using it as an aggregate.